# Root View Controller discrepancy between iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, ios8

My app is crashing on iOS7 since for some reason the `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController` instead of a `UISplitViewController`. So the app crashes on the first line which is `let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController` in `AppDelegate`. Is there like a fix or workaround for this? It works fine on iOS8

Comment: What devices (Physical or Simulated) are you testing this app on just curious?

Comment: It showed up on an iPhone 4S that was on 7.1.2 and I tried it on the simulator running 7.1 to try to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the issue is UISplitViewController is only used for iPads, not iPhones.  So make sure your target under your project is set to iPads only if you need to have a UISplitViewController. If you want to support both devices I would recommend checking to see which device idiom your app is currently running on launch and alternate between two storyboards (If you do that make sure your target is for Universal devices instead of just iPad). <--- This covers iOS 7 support, and the reason for the app not crashing on iOS 8 is because the UISplitViewController is now allowed on all iOS devices when it was not allowed on iPhones in iOS 7.

Comment: Then why does it run on fine on both iPad and iPhone for iOS8?

Comment: This is a quote from the UISplitViewController class reference. "In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all iOS devices; in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad." So I would check the iOS version before executing a different storyboard ahead of time to see if its even necessary to switch.

Comment: Is it like a huge workaround to support ios7 if it was coded with split view controller in mind?

Comment: No, you just have different view controllers that will call the same similar methods. You probably will have to make the interface a little different though.